# Management.Azure.com REST API Call with Odata $expand and $filter | body results not filtering

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rest-api

I am unable to get the desired results using a $expand and $filter in Odata on a REST API GET call. Basically looking to filter results so only properties.status = 'Closed' are returned on the GET API call. So far the expand and filters receive 200 OK but are not honoring the filtering in the body results.

https://**management.azure.com**/subscriptions/{SUBID}/resourceGroups/{RGNAME}/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/{WorkspaceName}/providers/Microsoft.SecurityInsights/Cases?api-version=2019-01-01-preview&$expand=properties($filter=status eq 'Closed')

[image: results]

eventually adding a 2nd filter like:

&$expand=properties($filter=status eq 'Closed' and relatedalertproductnames eq 'Azure Security Center')

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're specifying the `$filter` criteria incorrectly. Please try something like the following:

```
$expand=properties&$filter=properties/status eq 'New'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following to work as the values were not in an array but an object.

&$filter=(properties/status eq 'Closed')

Answer (score 0):

Add a plus sign so it takes it as one query

e.g. &$expand=..&$select=..+$filter=...